# ¿Cómo podría mostrar primero los registros %Bike% y despues %cycle% en la misma consulta?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

```
select c.CompanyName from SalesLT.Customer c
where (c.CompanyName like '%Bike%' or c.CompanyName like '%cycle%' );
```

Comment: Explica lo que entiendes aquí por *primero*  y *después*, poniendo un ejemplo de los resultados esperados. A simple vista parecería que con un simple `ORDER BY c.CompanyName` tendrías lo que esperas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que se puede es dar un orden específico en función del contenido encontrado, mediante un `CASE` hacemos aparecer primero las ocurrencias de `Bike`:

```
select c.CompanyName 
       from SalesLT.Customer c
       where (c.CompanyName like '%Bike%' or c.CompanyName like '%cycle%')
       order by (case when c.CompanyName like '%Bike%' then 1 else 2 end)
;
```

Comment: Hola y buenas tardes, revisando de nuevo la pregunta me surge una duda, usando el método que propone quedaría realmente ordenada la información?evidentemente primero mostraría los bike y después los cycles, pero los registros que coincidan con bike estarían ordenados entre ellos, y los que lo hagan con cycle estarían ordenados entre ellos?, espero haberme hecho entender, saludos cordiales

Comment: @Japv, el orden es solo por el contenido, si dentro de ese grupo se busca ordenar por otra columna, se la agrega al `order by`

Comment: Me refiero a que evidentemente primero salgan las coincidencias con bikes ordenadas entre ellas y después las coincidencias con cycle ordenadas entre ellas, por el mismo campo companyname

Comment: Eso es que decía:  `order by (case when c.CompanyName like '%Bike%' then 1 else 2 end), c.Company`

Comment: Correctisimo...

Answer (score 1):

Utiliza el **operador de conjuntos union**.

```
select c.CompanyName from SalesLT.Customer c
where c.CompanyName like '%Bike%'
order by c.Company
union
select c.CompanyName from SalesLT.Customer c
where c.CompanyName like '%cycle%'
order by c.Company
```

Este **operador de union** concatena en una misma salida los registros obtenidos en la primera consulta la cual obtiene los valores del **campo CompanyName** que matcheen con la expresión regular **%Bike%** con los valores obtenidos en la segunda consulta la cual obtiene los valores del **campo CompanyName** que matcheen con la expresion regular **%cycle%**.

Para que halla un verdadero ordenamiento alfabético utilizamos la **cláusula order by** en ambas consultas, de modo que los registros devueltos por ambas consultas queden ordenados independientemente de la unión que se hace a ambas consultas.